# Creating equidistant sampling points in polygon in QGIS 3.6.0?

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, sampling, soil

I have figured out how to add random points inside polygon boundaries. Although this works well, nevertheless I need a few different things to happen for my application.

What I would like to do is get equidistant points (5-acre square) within multiple polygon boundaries. I can somewhat replicate this result with random point generation but I can't buffer the points from the edge of the polygon which would be nice.

Additionally, when I use `Vector -> Research Tools -> Random points in layer bounds`, the points are generated with random numbered attributes, meaning there is no relation to the polygon boundary. Because these are used for sampling I assume that will get a bit frustrating when one area is not in order ie. `"Field 1"` has samples 1, 5, 8 but `"Field 2"` has 2, 4, 20 etc.

I have tried the regular point generation but it does not clip to each boundary which in a large data-set will take forever to do it with each boundary.

If anyone has any idea how to get regular points within each polygon on a multipart polygon layer?